# oracle rounding up

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to round up to the nearest bigger value, like that:

```
0.8333333 -> 9
1.5333333 -> 16
```

I am using round like:

```
SELECT ROUND(0.8333333,1) "Round" FROM DUAL;
```

But I am getting 8 and 15 instead, like:

```
0.8333333 -> 8
1.5333333 -> 15
```

I tried something with the other round functions, but it is not working. Could you please help.
Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  Are you sure this is not something about how you are reading the values?

Comment: I'm not clear what it is you seek. Why would any function "round" 1.5xxx to 16? Do you mean 1.6?

Comment: Are you expecting  9 or 0.9?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Correct is 0.9 and 1.6!

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like

```
SELECT CEIL(1.5333333 * 10) / 10 "Round" FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ceil(0.8333333*10) "Round" FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, you should flag it as such :-)

Comment: If the expected result is 0.9 this is not what you want.

Answer (score -3):

This works perfectly for my case:

```
SELECT ceil(0.8333333*10) "Round" FROM DUAL;
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Do not duplicate the answer that helped you. **Accept** _that_ answer.

Comment: why repeat the answer from 2 others? Just mark their answer as right.